# How to select values from last three fridays from Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table like below, that records in each minute values. I need to make a select that return the values from last three specific days of the week from 12:00 to 18:00, for example last 3 fridays, or last 3 mondays always from 12:00 to 18hs, how can i do that?

```
     timestamp         | value
01/06/2020 00:00          10
01/06/2020 00:01          05
01/06/2020 00:02          14
01/06/2020 00:03          20
01/06/2020 00:04          15
01/06/2020 00:05          06
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NEXT_DAY` to get the last three Fridays and compare it with your column as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE 
   -- CONDITION FOR LAST THREE FRIDAYS
   TRUNC(YOUR_COLUMN) IN (
    TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 8,'FRI')),
    TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 15,'FRI')),
    TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 22,'FRI'))
    ) 
   -- CONDITION FOR 12 TO 18 HOURS
   AND YOUR_COLUMN - TRUNC(YOUR_COLUMN) BETWEEN 12/24 and 18/24;
```

Comment: Its returning this ORA-00932: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: What is datatype of your column? Date or timestamp?

Comment: Sorry about that, the column name is "timestamp", but the datatype is Date.

Comment: Wow, it worked!! And the last detail, get just the max value in each this three days, between 12 and 18hs?

Comment: use `max` aggregate function with `group by` as `select max(YOUR_COLUMN)... group by TRUNC(YOUR_COLUMN)` will give you max per Friday.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yoy help!!

Comment: do you know why in InteliJ the query is returning ORA-01846 invalid day of the week ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  -- Where there are 4 days since the start of the ISO-week (Monday)
       -- so this would find all Fridays
       TRUNC( "timestamp" ) - TRUNC( "timestamp", 'IW' ) = 4
       -- Where the time interval since midnight of that day is between
       -- 12:00 and 18:00.
AND    ( "timestamp" - TRUNC( "timestamp" ) ) DAY TO SECOND
       BETWEEN INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
       AND     INTERVAL '18:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
       -- Where the timestamp is after 14 days before the start of this week
       -- (i.e. in this week or the previous 2 weeks).
AND    "timestamp" >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '14' DAY
       -- Where the timestamp is before 14 days before the start of this week
       -- (i.e. in this week or the previous 2 weeks).
AND    "timestamp" <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '7' DAY
```

Which for some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("timestamp", value) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-06-18' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-19' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-19' + INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-20' + INTERVAL '02:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-21' + INTERVAL '03:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-22' + INTERVAL '04:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-23' + INTERVAL '05:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-24' + INTERVAL '06:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-25' + INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-26' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-27' + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-28' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-29' + INTERVAL '11:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 41 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-06-30' + INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-07-01' + INTERVAL '13:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 61 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-07-02' + INTERVAL '14:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-07-03' + INTERVAL '15:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 81 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> timestamp           | VALUE
> :------------------ | ----:
> 2020-06-19 15:00:00 |    30
> 2020-07-03 15:00:00 |    81
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3cb01fe57cc6f0a990cd6dfc4b48b8c)*

Comment: And, how to get the max value between 12 an 18hs?

Comment: @Jovani `GROUP BY` the day and use `MAX`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yoy help!!